# Removing Duplicate values and adding 0 on their place

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I have written a code to remove duplicate values and add 0 on there place .
But i feel like my code should be much better than this,if anybody can give a better idea of developing this code.
Please suggest me and advice me.

- Input--2,3,4,3,6
- output--2,3,4,0,6

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a[100],b[100];
   int i,j,size;
   scanf("%d",&size);
   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
      scanf("%d",&a[i]);
   }

   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
      b[i]=a[i];

   }

   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
      for(j=i+1;j<size;j++)
      {
         if(a[i]==a[j])
         {
            b[j]=0;
         }
      }
   }

   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
      printf("%d\n",b[i]);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: One optimization could be using just one array, and modifying on `a` instead of copying into `b`.

Comment: @how to implement that because,i know for large number of digits it will make my program very slow.

Comment: You are using an O(n^2) already. Could check in the same array.

Comment: @DeepakKumar : So after following the discussion a bit, you are looking for time complexity improvements, right? Better state that in your question. How many  numbers are we talking about?

Comment: @GregorOphey  i guess near about 1000 numbers.

Comment: @DeepakKumar : I would not wory about efficiency in this case, unless your platform is VERY restricted (like, let's say you have to role-enact the algorithm during an exam :-) ). Focus on correctness and readability.

Answer (score 1):

Clear duplicates as they are entered as follows, comparing with the values entered so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  int a[100];
  int i,j,size;
  scanf("%d",&size);
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
      scanf("%d",&a[i]);
      for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        if(a[j]==a[i]) {
          a[i]=0; /* found duplicate among previous entries! */
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    printf("%d\n",a[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that any more efficient that original solution? or just "shorter" code? Besides, the question is more general than processing input, it's about finding and clearing duplicates in an array

Comment: @Amit : well, it is shorter code (less room for bugs ...). Plus it is more space efficient, saving array b entirely. And the break makes it time efficient on average. You can use the same approach when the array is already filled in, of course.

Comment: @gregor suppose i add a constraint that instead of adding 0 i just have to trim duplicate value.Is it implementable here???

Comment: @DeepakKumar : In that case (as in others where the length is affected) I would not do this in place, rather I would allocate a fresh array of same size and copy all values not seen before, then resize the result

Comment: @GregorOphey - you're right, it is more efficient on average.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an improvement, but I agree it feels like it can be significantly better (Maybe I'll get back to this later...):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a[100];
   int i,j,size,left;
   scanf("%d",&size);
   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
      scanf("%d",&a[i]);
   }

   left = size;
   for(i=0;i<size&&left>1;i++) // If there's only 1 left, it's not a duplicate
   {
      if(a[i] == 0) // No need to test these, already done
         continue;

      for(j=i+1,left=0;j<size;j++)
      {
         if(a[i]==a[j])
         {
            a[j]=0;
         }
         if(a[j]!=0)
            left++; // If we don't get here, there's nothing left to test
      }
   }

   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
      printf("%d\n",a[i]);

   return 0;
}
```

So basically, don't search for 0's ahead of current position, and when searching for anything else count (mark actually) if there is anything left to test.

Comment: but the problem remains the same if i am having huge number of values than it will make my program slow.

Comment: Because copying of one array to another will increase the time complexity.

Comment: If you don't need to keep the original array, it's easier... I did that since that's your original code. Editing answer...

Answer (score 0):

Here is some of my idea:

**Solution 1:**

Use bit to indicate whether a number occurred yet.
e.g On 32bit machine, 1 int has 32bit, if your number range is 1 ~ 1000, then you need 32 int, you can change it range when you met a larger number, by `realloc()`.

If your number range is small, then it's quite suitable.

**Solution 2:**

Store sorted numbers in a binary tree, so that you can search quicker.

Comment: seems implementable  let me do that.

Comment: @ Eric yes it is.Because Traversing in a tree is quite easy than array.

Comment: @Eric your 2nd solution is very good, but would probably be counteractive on the "limited" problem in the original question (Array of size < 100). On a large scale, BST is an obvious optimization, although depending on specific problem details, a balancing BST might be required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the single array itself, and mark at the positions where you find a duplicate in it. Something like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[100];
    int i,j,size;
    scanf("%d",&size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    for(i=1; i<size; i++) {
        for(j=i-1; j>=0; j--) {
            if(a[i]==a[j]) {
                a[i]=0;
                break;
            }      
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This won't have the same output as the original sample (you'll get -2,0,4,3,6), but that's easy to solve by flipping the search direction.

Comment: No, you would get (2,0,4,3,6) if `a[j]=0` were used, but not with `a[i]=0` like I used.

Comment: @ Anindya but then it makes the program totally different because first value is never the duplicate in the list the other ones which comes after that are duplicates;

Comment: Exactly, the first one is never the duplicate, so you don't need to check it. From the next index, you check with only those numbers which have occurred before it, because if that element is a duplicate, it would have the same number somewhere before it. Try the code on a compiler and see how it works. :)

Comment: @AnindyaDutta - You're right, your code confused me, but you're right... However, since you're clearing the array "backwards", every time you look for a number you have to find the first occurrence of that number starting at the end. So for example for this sequence `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1...`, every item goes from i-1 to 0. That's less efficient than the other direction (See my code).

Comment: @AnindyaDutta even Gregor has also given a nice code,you can see that also.

Comment: @DeepakKumar - Anindya didn't respond to my comment, so I'm drawing your attention to the fact that this solution is inefficient.

Comment: @Amit describe me the inefficiency of the code briefly.

Comment: @DeepakKumar, I did... look at my comment above, or simply imagine how the algorithm behaves on a series of 1's (1 1 1 1 1 1...)

Comment: @Amit Yes the code does seem inefficient when compared to your code, especially one where the repetitions are more and the original number is towards the left end of the array.